# MySQL select only rows remaining

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table like:

```
id | name   | type  
 1 | a      | in  
 2 | a      | out  
 3 | a      | in  
 4 | a      | out  
 5 | a      | in  
 6 | b      | in  
 7 | b      | out  
 8 | b      | in  
 9 | c      | in  
10 | c      | out
```

I want to select all the `in` events that have no matching `out` event.

```
5 | a  | in  
8 | b  | in
```

is it possible?

Edit:

ins and outs have same name don't have to follow each other.

```
id | name   | type  
 1 | a      | in  
 2 | a      | out  
 3 | a      | in  
 4 | a      | out  
 5 | c      | in  
 6 | b      | in  
 7 | b      | out  
 8 | b      | in  
 9 | a      | in  
10 | c      | out
```

Comment: Why would it only select these?  There are other rows with type "in"; if it has to do with the name, why isn't `9|c|in` included?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the question.

Comment: Only rows with type "in" not outed with an equivalent row with type "out".. 1 outed by 2, 3 outed by 4, 6 outed by 7 and 9 outed by 10.

Comment: Can we assume that matched events are always consecutive, or is a sequence like `a - in`, `b - in`,`a - out`, `b - out` possible?

Comment: Yes Hobo Sapiens. That's what I mean exactly. Thanks.

Comment: is it the count that has to match (**in**s not matching **out**s), or is the order important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a `not exists` predicate with a correlated subquery that checks that there doesn't exists any 'out' row with a higher id than the 'in' row (where the name is the same).

```
select * from table1 a
where type = 'in'
and not exists (
  select 1 from table1 b 
  where a.name = b.name 
  and b.type = 'out' 
  and b.id > a.id
);
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d7e57/1)

Answer (score 0):

here ya go....

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.name,t1.type
FROM `t` t1
JOIN `t` t2 on t1.id + 1=t2.id
where t2.type = t1.type
```

and here is the complete sql fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90d87/6

- I've matched the table to itself on an offset of 1: `t1.id+1 = t2.id`
- then I pull only the ones that are the same: `where t2.type = t1.type`

this would match anything that is consecutively same, if **out**s happen as well and need to watch for that, use `where t2.type = t1.type AND t1.type = 'in'`